# How convert html to BBcode in C#

Tags: c#, html, bbcode

I need to convert **html** text into **bbcodes**. Where i can find how should i do this? For example, I convert links:

```
 regex = new Regex("<a href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)</a>");
 htmlCode = regex.Replace(htmlCode, "[URL]$1[/URL]");
```

How can i convert all html tags in bbcodes (and replace to empty which isn't bb codes, tag **P**

Comment: [You cannot parse HTML using regular expressions!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: i've read this post, i know. But. I have user input. and user will input to programm html in normal format. I make user input format. i hope you understand me.. =)

Comment: You can still work on user input using DOM manipulation libraries. And in any case, it's impossible to losslessly convert from HTML to BBCode, since the latter doesn't support everything that the former does.

Comment: You cannot even parse normal HTML using regular expressions.

Comment: i can lost any tags, for example: color, hr, span (not data) etc.

Comment: You still can't.  You cannot parse any nested structure using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *some* HTML tags, you can just do a simple `string.Replace`.  BBCode is in many ways just a 1:1, tag-for-tag mapping, for example `<b>` and `</b>` mapping to `[B]` and `[/B]` respectively.  So that's easily accomplished with just:

```
html.Replace("<b>", "[b]").Replace("</b>", "[/b]")
```

If it's really dead-simple HTML, and you don't mind the performance impact and code ugliness of doing this tag-by-tag, go for it.  But beware of cross-site scripting vulnerabilities, if you plan to display the resulting BBCode on a web page somewhere; this is nowhere near good enough for sanitization.

But don't even bother trying to use regular expressions to sanitize the HTML and do automatic replacement of all tags.  The `<img>` tag, for instance, looks completely different in HTML vs. BBCode.  In HTML it's `<img src="..."/>` (trailing slash is optional) and in BBCode it's `[IMG]...[/IMG]`.  Doing this with regex is... well, let's just say sub-optimal.

Regular expressions are designed for regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language, it's a context-free language.  Consider using an actual HTML parser instead like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  Then you can descend the DOM tree, whitelist the elements you want, and map them to BBCode or anything else however you like.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use Regexs (which *cannot* ever ever ever parse HTML), try using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to search down the DOM tree and change the relevant HTML tags into BBCode. Making a new *valid* BBCode document would seem to be the hardest part of this - maybe there is some library to help make valid BBCode markup somewhere?

Comment: oh,, no))
i have clear xhtml. some tags: p,b,u,i,span,br,strong,h1-h6... thats all..)

Comment: What do you mean by "clear xhtml"? You still need to (well, should) use a parser for elements like `<a href=....` which do not have a one to one mapping with BBcode.

Comment: i have clear link: only <a href="xx">name</a> only this. other i can lost

Comment: If it is only `<a href="xx">name</a>` and is _always in that exact format_ then you could use a regex. It would be quicker than the DOM tree method.

Answer (score 0):

I know your suppose to use a tool built for parsing the DOM aka HtmlAgilityPack but I needed something that could use the tools built into .net and not have to reference an external dll.

So I wrote a converter in c# that does it all through RegEx.

Here's my write-up http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/convert-html-to-bbcode-in-c/