# Replace string with condition

Tags: c#, str-replace

I'm implementing a library that will convert `BBCode`-like syntax to a corresponding html element. I can easily do it on simple element by using `String.Replace` function. E.x:

```
string text = "this is [b]some text that need to parse[/b] and more text to make it more complicated [i]and then more text that need to parse[/i], how fun";
text = text.Replace("[b]", "<b>");
text = text.Replace("[/b]", "</b>");
text = text.Replace("[i]", "<i>");
text = text.Replace("[/i]", "</i>");
```

But with a complex element like `[code class="c-sharp"][/code]`. I don't know how to replace `[code][/code]` with `<pre></pre>` but still preserve the `class="c-sharp"` attribute. Is there any solution for this case without using `regular expression`? Because I want to preserve the readability of my code.

Comment: http://bbcode.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think this solution simplifies your problem [Codekicker BBCode parser](http://bbcode.codeplex.com)

Comment: You should use regular expression
May be this [will help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708857/how-convert-html-to-bbcode-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code:

```
string s = "[code class='c-sharp'][/code]";
StringBuilder pre = new StringBuilder(s);

pre.Replace("[","<");
pre.Replace("]",">");
pre.Replace("code","pre");
```

Hint: You can use the first and second replaces as default because it's common between your scenarios.

[image: Example using LinqPad]

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is straightforward and easy to understand